# Merging Audio file with Video file in Flutter

Tags: flutter, audio, video

I am working on an app which has similar functionality like Instagram reels. I want to know how do I merge a song(audio) while recording the video and then store them both as a video.

Comment: Can you specify which specific plugins you are using for the audio and video playback

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will do using [flutter_ffmpeg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg) package.

create a command like this.

```
  command = "-y -i $videoPath -i $audioPath -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v copy "
              "-shortest $savedFileLocation"
```

to execute command using

```
 final FlutterFFmpeg _flutterFFmpeg = FlutterFFmpeg();
      _flutterFFmpeg.execute(command.string).then((rc) {
        statusCode = rc;
        print("FFmpeg process exited with rc $rc");
        return statusCode;
      });
```

Comment: This package is discontinued...Have you any other solution ?

Comment: ffmpeg_kit_flutter: ^4.5.1 you can check